# Laravel 8 | App folder filled with unknown errors

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

[image]

namespace and use aren't recognized in any of the app folder files.
What can cause this?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Does it support composer projects? Did you set up the project root to the folder containing your `composer.json` file correctly?  Did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: @apokryfos Visual Studio Code, I installed laravel via composer, what does that mean, the root folder thing?

Comment: i think you have install some extension so these errors are genrated in visual studio code .  remove recently extensions from your visual studio code .

Comment: Can you share how you installed Laravel using composer? Was it the steps [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer) ? If so you need to be sure to open the folder that is created when your run that command. That folder will contain a `composer.json` and (assuming using the correct composer plugin) VS code can read it correctly.

Comment: @apokryfos I created a environment variable in 'Path', into c:/xampp/php, and then installed composer on it, then i did the installation trough 'composer global require laravel/installer' and then created the project.

Comment: you have  to uninstall all extensions from visual code studio  or   uninstall vsc then install  agian you will get your solution .

Comment: also run command php artisan optimize its runs perfectly then problem in vsc reinsatll it .

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad Your suggestion also doesn't work.